# How to pass TDictionary as an optional parameter?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How to pass TDictionary as an optional parameter?

For instance, if I use it inside a class doesn't work:

```
TMyDict = TDictionary<String, String>;

TTest = class
   procedure Render(Id: Integer; Name: String = ''; Variables: TMyDict = nil); //error
end;
```

I don't know why, but this code works fine. However I can't use it.

```
procedure Render(Id: Integer; Name: String = ''; Variables: TMyDict = nil);
begin
   // Do something...
end;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a line of code marked "error"; plesae tell *which* error you get. Copy and paste the error message. You say you have code that "works fine," but then you say you "can't use it." If it works fine, what's stopping you from using it?

Comment: In the future, when you say "doesn't work", explain what "doesn't work" means. We can't see your screen from here or read your thoughts, so it's much easier if you just tell us (as you already know how it "doesn't work"). Also, when you say "error", please explain what that means as well, and include the *exact* error message if you're getting one. It makes it much easier to help you if you actually provide us the information with which we can do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your declaration of the implementation is missing the class. It should be:

```
procedure TTest.Render(Id: Integer; Name: String = ''; Variables: TMyDict = nil);
//        ^^^^^^
begin
   // Do something...
end;
```

You might also consider omitting the default values in the implementation.

Here's a complete program that compiles, to illustrate the point:

```
program SO16740725;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Generics.Collections;

type
  TMyDict = TDictionary<string, string>;

type
  TTest = class
    procedure Render(Id: Integer; Name: string=''; Variables: TMyDict=nil);
  end;

procedure TTest.Render(Id: Integer; Name: string; Variables: TMyDict);
begin
   // Do something...
end;

begin
end.
```

Comment: my preference would be to keep the implementation 100% equal (so include the default value) to avoid confusion...